# Is it possible to create something like a requirements file for homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

Python (and other languages) can use a requirements file to specify a list of packages to install.

Is it possible to use a requirements file for homebrew?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [brew bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle), which installs as a subcommand of `brew`. It can install and update packages, taps, and casks specified in a *Brewfile*. You can also dump your current Homebrew environment into a new *Brewfile* or uninstall everything not listed.